# missing faces on smd model

Tags: mesh

I've been working on a bunch of models lately but when I went back onto Blender a day later for some reason this has happened

[image]

It happened to all models I've made, the faces are like they've been deleted by themselves. I tried to look for hidden faces and nothing happened.

I compiled the model into the source engine and the model looks fine, tried reinstalling Blender, system restart from yesterday and still nothings changed.

Is there a way to fix this that doesn't involve individually filling in the faces?

Comment: If model looks fine in the engine you mention then maybe this change is somehow not destructive or done on another copy of the model. If this edit was made destructively (editing mesh data) and there aren't any backups then likely no fast way to repair that other than e.g. modeling another mesh and using Shrinkwrap to wrap it onto surface of this one. Though more info needed to diagnose what is that. Try pressing Alt+H, try looking for any modifiers in the stack, if you want to share the file use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is it possible that the normals on those faces are flipped? In edit mode press A to select all the faces and press Ctrl+N to recalculate normals

Answer (score 1):

When importing make sure you select these options:

[image: Options]