# All .smd meshes I import into blender have missing triangles

Tags: mesh

[image: Whenever I import a mesh it looks like this. I don't know if this is a setting or anything like that, but I didn't have this problem a week ago.]

I can no longer rig or weight paint models because it is so hard to see the bones and things with the pieces missing. I have reinstalled Blender, and all models I have used have are like this. I have gone through like 10 models trying to find one that works, but none of them do.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102260/missing-faces-on-smd-model

Comment: Thank you so much!